# Wicket 6.3.0 AjaxLink: IAjaxCallListener behaviour

Tags: ajax, wicket

Prior to Wicket 6  the javascript code returned by IAjaxCallDecorator.decorateScipt was executed immediately after a click. I migrated IAjaxCallDecorator according to the [migration-guide](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Wicket+Ajax). 
By clicking 3 times the link within 5 seconds the expected result is:

- getPrecondition
- getPrecondition
- getPrecondition
- getSuccessHandler
- getSuccessHandler
- getSuccessHandler

But the result was:

- getPrecondition
- getSuccessHandler
- getPrecondition
- getSuccessHandler
- getPrecondition
- getSuccessHandler

Use case: Blocking until an Ajax request is complete see http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/-/9781849511605/deeper-into-ajax/ch07lvl1sec04 (Page 162)

Is there another way to migrate IAjaxCallDecorator to Wicket 6?

```
public class HomePage extends WebPage {

 public HomePage(final PageParameters parameters) {
  add(new Label("version", getApplication().getFrameworkSettings().getVersion()));

  AjaxLink<Void> blockingLink = new AjaxLink<Void>("blockingLink") {
    @Override
    public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
      try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
    @Override
    protected void updateAjaxAttributes(AjaxRequestAttributes attributes) {
      super.updateAjaxAttributes(attributes);

      IAjaxCallListener blockingListener = new AjaxCallListener() {
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPrecondition(Component component) {
          return "console.log('getPrecondition');";
        }
        @Override
        public CharSequence getSuccessHandler(Component component) {
          return "console.log('getSuccessHandler');";
        }
      };
      attributes.getAjaxCallListeners().add(blockingListener);
    }
  };
  add(blockingLink);
 }
}
```

Comment: AFAICS there's no hook method that is invoked *before* the call is queued. What do you need this for?

Comment: Blocking until an Ajax request is complete see http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/-/9781849511605/deeper-into-ajax/ch07lvl1sec04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use case: Blocking until an Ajax request is complete see http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/-/9781849511605/deeper-into-ajax/ch07lvl1sec04
(Page 162)

```
@Override
protected void updateAjaxAttributes(AjaxRequestAttributes attributes) {
  super.updateAjaxAttributes(attributes);
  attributes.setChannel(new AjaxChannel("myChannel", AjaxChannel.Type.ACTIVE));
}
```

did the job. see [wicket forum](http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/Wicket-6-3-0-AjaxLink-IAjaxCallListener-behaviour-td4654785.html#a4654804)